# To run http trigger from Azure Data Factory by Schedule Trigger in ADF

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-http-trigger

I try to use triggers to run httptrigger from the Azure Data Factory. But I get a timeout error message instead. Because the ADF function app activity only lasts 230 seconds, Httptrigger does not respond in that period.It displays the timeout issue as shown in the picture.

[image: 2]

But at the same time httptrigger runs and finish it self (as you can see this picture)

[image: 1]

Is there anyone who could assist me in resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Microsoft official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout):

> Regardless of the function app timeout setting, 230 seconds is the
> maximum amount of time that an HTTP triggered function can take to
> respond to a request. This is because of the default idle timeout of
> Azure Load Balancer.

To work around this behavior, follow an **async pattern** or use **Durable Functions**. **The benefit of Durable Functions is that they offer their own state-tracking mechanism, so you don't need to implement your own state-tracking.**

To know more about Durable Functions async pattern please check [this official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#async-http).